# WooCommerce - Custom product category template

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce

I am trying to create a different display for a given category in WooCommerce. For example, if there is a category `clothes` and another `bikes`. I want the `clothes` one to display as usual, but to change the layout for the `bikes` one.

I did some research, but couldn't find anything that worked for me. I tried the documentation here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ but am not sure how to use it exactly.

Please, if anyone has been through this process, could you give me a detailed example maybe?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you talking about the store view, where you see all products from a given category or are you talking about the "product single" view, where you see the detailed information about a single product?

Comment: Thank you @jrswgtr I am talking about the store view where you see a list of all the products from a given category

Comment: Does your URL look like `store/?filter_category=clothing` ?

Comment: No, this would be filtering the whole store, I mean when you go to a specific category `product-category/bikes/` for example

Comment: What are you trying to change and where exactly… With conditional tags, you can make changes on any template for a specific case like a  specific product category on product category archive pages: `if( is_product_category( 'bikes' ) ) { // specific "bikes" content } else { // Other cases }`

Comment: I see, is that inside of the `woocommerce/content-product_cat.php` ? I wanted to create a separate template and then assign it to the category view for that specific category. But I will look at doing it conditionally as you said in that template. Thank you @LoicTheAztec

Comment: Not necessarily … It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: It's simple, if you go to `/product-category/bikes/` in the shop as a customer, I want to display the list of products in one way and you if you go to `/product-category/clothes/` to display it in a different way.